# SQL Server : trigger how to read value for Insert, Update, Delete

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have the trigger in one table and would like to read `UserId` value when a row is inserted, updated or deleted. How to do that? The code below does not work, I get error on `UPDATED`

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[UpdateUserCreditsLeft] 
   ON  [dbo].[Order]
   AFTER INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE 
    @UserId INT,

    SELECT @UserId = INSERTED.UserId FROM INSERTED, DELETED

    UPDATE dbo.[User] SET CreditsLeft = CreditsLeft - 1 WHERE Id = @UserId
END
```

Comment: It's *also* wrong because there can be multiple rows in these tables, so trying to read a value into a variable will give you one of those row's values (which one is undefined).

Comment: In addition to writing a triiger that think only one row will be changed which is a poor practice, you have used implicit joins which is also a sql antipattern. Do not ever use implied joins. Right now you havea cross join which you probably did not want. It is inexcusable to be writing such code almost 20 years after implict joins were replaced with the far better explicit joins.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Please note that `inserted, deleted` means the same thing as `inserted CROSS JOIN deleted` and gives every combination of every row.  I doubt this is what you want.

Something like this may help get you started...

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN inserted.primaryKey IS NULL THEN 'This is a delete'
       WHEN  deleted.primaryKey IS NULL THEN 'This is an insert'
                                        ELSE 'This is an update'
  END  as Action,
  *
FROM
  inserted
FULL OUTER JOIN
  deleted
    ON inserted.primaryKey = deleted.primaryKey
```

Depending on what you want to do, you then reference the table you are interested in with `inserted.userID` or `deleted.userID`, etc.

Finally, be aware that `inserted` and `deleted` are *tables* and can (and do) contain more than one record.

If you insert 10 records at once, the `inserted` table will contain ALL 10 records.  The same applies to deletes and the `deleted` table.  And both tables in the case of an update.

**EDIT** Examplee Trigger after OPs edit.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[UpdateUserCreditsLeft] 
  ON  [dbo].[Order]
  AFTER INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE
AS 
BEGIN

  -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
  -- interfering with SELECT statements.
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  UPDATE
    User
  SET
    CreditsLeft = CASE WHEN inserted.UserID IS NULL THEN <new value for a  DELETE>
                       WHEN  deleted.UserID IS NULL THEN <new value for an INSERT>
                                                    ELSE <new value for an UPDATE>
                  END
  FROM
    User
  INNER JOIN
    (
      inserted
    FULL OUTER JOIN
      deleted
        ON inserted.UserID = deleted.UserID  -- This assumes UserID is the PK on UpdateUserCreditsLeft
    )
      ON User.UserID = COALESCE(inserted.UserID, deleted.UserID)

END
```

If the PrimaryKey of `UpdateUserCreditsLeft` is something other than UserID, use that in the FULL OUTER JOIN instead.

Comment: great answer, this one saved my job today

Comment: What does "<new value for a  DELETE/iNSERT/UPDATE>" mean in this case? Not sure what to put there in my case

Answer (score 33):

**There is no `updated` dynamic table.**  There is just `inserted` and `deleted`.  On an `UPDATE` command, the old data is stored in the `deleted` dynamic table, and the new values are stored in the `inserted` dynamic table.

Think of an `UPDATE` as a `DELETE/INSERT` combination.

Comment: I have changed line to SELECT @UserId = UserId FROM INSERTED, DELETED and now I get error Ambiguous column name 'UserId'.

Comment: @Tomas - See my answer, I don't think `,` means what you think it means.

Comment: @Tomas you need to specify the source of the `UserId` field.  For instance, do something like `select @UserId = inserted.UserId from inserted, deleted`

Comment: @Tomas Dems may be right.  The `comma` indicates a join.  Is this your desire?

Comment: The code which I needed select @UserId = inserted.UserId from inserted, deleted

Comment: @Tomas - This assumes that only one record is ever written.  Also, if you CROSS JOIN (using `,`) these tables for an INSERT or a DELETE one or other table will be empty and so the CROSS JOIN will yield no records.  You need to code this with a `JOIN` instead of a `,` and in such a way that it can handle multiple records being written in one go.  Please heed Damien's comment on your question and the notes in my answer, or you will fall into a trap sooner or later.

Comment: @Dems I am new to trigger things and I have edited and posted my full code. Could you please update your post with full trigger code? And thank you for your note!

Answer (score -7):

Here is the syntax to create a trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name
ON { table | view }
[ WITH ENCRYPTION ]
{
    { { FOR | AFTER | INSTEAD OF } { [ INSERT ] [ , ] [ UPDATE ] [ , ] [ DELETE ] }
        [ WITH APPEND ]
        [ NOT FOR REPLICATION ]
        AS
        [ { IF UPDATE ( column )
            [ { AND | OR } UPDATE ( column ) ]
                [ ...n ]
        | IF ( COLUMNS_UPDATED ( ) { bitwise_operator } updated_bitmask )
                { comparison_operator } column_bitmask [ ...n ]
        } ]
        sql_statement [ ...n ]
    }
}
```

If you want to use On Update you only can do it with the `IF UPDATE ( column )` section. That's not possible to do what you are asking.