# SQL Server 2017 trigger for old value as new value for AFTER UPDATE

Tags: sql-server, database, triggers, database-trigger

I use SQL Server 2017 Management Studio. I need a trigger (`trigg_1`) for `AFTER UPDATE` which inserts in column `col_1` the old value instead of new value. I will manually change column `col_1` with new value and trigger needs to change `col_1` with old value.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigg_1 
ON table_1 
AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN

END
GO
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server : trigger how to read value for Insert, Update, Delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8505924/sql-server-trigger-how-to-read-value-for-insert-update-delete) The value you want would be in the Deleted table, an Update Deletes then Inserts.

Comment: So value of `col_1` can't be updated?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  It is unclear what data should be changed by the trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigg_1 
   ON  table_1 
   AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN

    UPDATE  T2
    SET     T2.COL_1 = T1.COL_1
    FROM    DELETED T1
    INNER JOIN TABLE_1 T2 ON T2.ID = T1.ID /* Here you must link by PK - I suggested PK contains only ID column. */

END
GO
```